# Best approach for creating a time sensitive browser app for desktop with high time precision?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, browser, timer

I have to develop an application that will be required to measure user response time within a series of experiments. This application will be run on approximately 100 computers, thus I had mentioned that a browser based approach might be best to cut down on performing installs and updates. With that said, now that I've read about the accuracy of timers in browsers, specifically javascript timers, I'm learning there can be a delay from a few milliseconds to upwards of 10-15ms. This sort of delay would have a negative impact on the precision of these experiments when users measure their response time to visual queues on the screen.

Is there a known way around this to get precise timers for a web application being run within a browser through javascript? Likewise, some of these experiments require simple 2d animation, such as seeing how long a user can keep their mouse cursor over a rotating cube. I would prefer to use HTML5 and Javascript and we cannot use flash.

Comment: You can't rely on javascript at all. 1) Javascript Dates (and timers) are based on system time. If the user changes their system time, there is no real way for javascript to know. For example, if you have a countdown of 1 minute, start it, then the user sets their time back 30 minutes, the timer would now be about 31 minutes.

Comment: See this: http://jsfiddle.net/ZqvPF/

Comment: Another problem is that with sophisticated javascript consoles (and plugins like greasemonkey) in browsers, the user can replace portions of your javascript to rig the timing in their favor.

Answer (score 2):

True you can't rely on a timer's interval, but you can rely on a new Date object. For instance:

```
var previousTime = new Date().getTime(); // returns milliseconds of "now"

var timer = setInterval( function() {
   var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
   var millisecondsSinceLastUpdate = currentTime - previousTime;
   previousTime = currentTime;
   alert( 'milliseconds since last update: ' + millisecondsSinceLastUpdate );
}, 1 );
```

Comment: You can see that as Snuffleupagus mentioned, even when using the Date.getTime it is still not accurate. If you look at the javascript demo he cited [link]http://jsfiddle.net/Ff6ZV/4/[/link], the example uses currenttime subtract previous time just like you have mentioned. The demo shows that across browsers it gives different response times. There is delay in the execution of the code and not really be accurate.

Comment: @Euthyphro Just because there are different times in that experiment, doesn't mean the time differences calculated are not accurate...

Comment: @Euthyphro For instance if you use the calculated time passed to move a sprite across a specific distance on a browser, using a distance of (timepassed * velocity) for each frame of the animation, the sprite would travel the same speed no matter what the system. The only vulnerability would be if the user messed with the system clock.

Comment: The thing is that each browser has  a different execution time so one browser may execute lines of javascript code faster than another, in which case they wouldn't be moving at the same speed. I understand what you are saying, but the problem is that javascript isnt compiled, the browser reads through the script at run time and some browsers can read through it faster than others, from my understanding. For example, if you have var aTime = new Date().getTime(); /*insert 100 lines of code*/ var bTime = new Date().getTime(); var executionTime = bTime - aTime; (see next post, ran out of space)

Comment: The end result would be different between browsers (chrome, FF, IE). This is problematic for me because it isn't accurately giving a response time based on how fast a user responds to what they see on screen. If one browser is crappy at executing javascript, it would screw up the experiment and give an inaccurate time because some of that time is dedicated to inefficient javascript execution through the browser, which would affect the time read out.

Answer (score 1):

Just as @dqhendricks suggests, you should use a new `Date` object. However, if you need this to be consistent and accurate you'd need this be run on the same computer with the same browser version and nothing running in the background.

Check out this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ff6ZV/2/) in firefox and chrome. Click on the edge and move your cursor out as fast as you can - the lowest I can get in FF is 6MS, the lowest I can get in Chrome is 42MS.

These values can vary even wider between machines. I set up a VM with 512MB of RAM and 50% single core cap, opened up 5 tabs in FF and attempted the test - the lowest I've gotten is 52MS.

So unless you can control the users browser, PC and things running in the background I would not count on the data being accurate.

Comment: the time calculated is still accurate. I don't understand what you are trying to prove with this experiment. Basically you are saying that different browsers take different amounts of time to perform certain actions. This does not mean that the time difference calculated is inaccurate.

Comment: @dqhendricks I was under the presumption you were going to be comparing response times between users, but because of the variables (browser, computer, etc.) you can't make an accurate comparison.

Answer (score 0):

If you have new browsers you can use performance.now() which offers more precision than the Date object, but the other performance concerns of using the browser still apply :(

http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/08/When-milliseconds-are-not-enough-performance-now